# How to create a new file in Perl?

Tags: perl, serialization, perl-io

I've some values stored in the variables `$a`,`$b`,`$c`.
Now I've to load these values into new file (create file & load).
I'm new to Perl, how can I do it?

Comment: Did you try to find the solution yourself? The Google search "how to write to a file in perl" gives 35.4 mio results

Comment: open FILE, ">", "filename.txt" or die $!

Comment: can anyone let me know if u know ?

Comment: @Jackie: from your comment you appear to know the answer. What further help do you need?

Comment: I want to create a new file & then load data into it. does above command create file by name filename.txt if it doesn't exist ?

Comment: @Jackie: yes it does. Then you can print to it using `print FILE $variable, 99, "string"` or similar. Experiment and you will see.

Comment: Regarding your question's title, please write ["perl" or "Perl" but never "PERL"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f).

Comment: `$a` and `$b` aren't good variable names in Perl, since they can conflict or cause confusion with `sort()`s built in `$a` and `$b` variables

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie qw(:all);

my $a = 5;
my $b = 3;
my $c = 10;

#### WRITE ####
{
    open my $fh, '>', 'output.txt';
    print {$fh} $a . "\n";
    print {$fh} $b . "\n";
    print {$fh} $c . "\n";
    close $fh;
}

#### READ ####
{
    open my $fh, '<', 'output.txt';
    my ($a, $b, $c) = <$fh>;
    print $a;
    print $b;
    print $c;
    close $fh;
}
```

You should read [perlopentut](http://p3rl.org/opentut) and [Beginner Perl Maven tutorial: Writing to files](http://perlmaven.com/writing-to-files-with-perl).

Answer (score 2):

Another option: [File::Slurp](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Slurp) provides convenient [`read_file`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp#read_file) and [`write_file`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp#write_file) functions

```
write_file('/path/file', @data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the methods `LoadFile` and `DumpFile` of the [`YAML`](https://metacpan.org/module/YAML) module. They are very easy to use as you just need to throw a filename and the actual data against them.

Ask specific questions if don't get along with these.